# Help in correcting the SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to solve this query. I have the following data:

```
Input
Date        Id      Value
25-May-2011 1       10
26-May-2011 1       10
26-May-2011 2       10
27-May-2011 1       20
27-May-2011 2       20
28-May-2011 1       10
```

I need to query and output as:

```
Output
FromDate    ToDate          Id    Value
25-May-2011 26-May-2011     1     10
26-May-2011 26-May-2011     2     10
27-May-2011 27-May-2011     1     20
28-May-2011 28-May-2011     1     10
```

I tried this sql but I'm not getting the correct result:

```
SELECT START_DATE, END_DATE, A.KEY, B.VALUE FROM
(
  SELECT MIN(DATE) START_DATE, KEY, VALUE
  FROM
  KEY_VALUE
  GROUP
  BY KEY,VALUE
) A INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT MAX(DATE) END_DATE, KEY, VALUE
  FROM
  KEY_VALUE
  GROUP
  BY KEY, VALUE
) B ON A.KEY = B.KEY AND A.VALUE = B.VALUE;
```

Comment: Your data is flawed because there's no way to order the rows for sure since you can have multiple rows on the same day. Without times, or better, an id indicating time order, any solution we give you will be flawed.

Comment: @Erik It is actually totally ordered by `(Date, Id)` ;-) I am not sure if this is intentional or by accident though.

Comment: @Erik Actually the id's are different. On same day we can have different ids and values.

Comment: Why should 27-May-2011 27-May-2011 1 20 ? Should it not be27-May-2011 27-May-2011 2 20

Comment: So are you saying that the `id` is the record number for the day? That was not clear. You need to explain more. We can't get all of the info from such a short sample just by guessing! My next question is, if a value did not change for several days are you looking for one row per day or one row that spans the whole range?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying too hard.  Should be more like this:

```
SELECT MIN(START_DATE) AS FromDate, MAX(END_DATE) AS ToDate, KEY, VALUE
FROM  KEY_VALUE
GROUP BY KEY, VALUE
```

Comment: I believe he is looking for an unbreaking span of days. Your query would give a result of 26-28 when there is no record on the 27th right? I wonder if you can add something like this to enforce span "HAVING EXISTS( _query to find date one day higher with same key/value_ ) OR EXISTS ( _query to find date one day higher with same key/value_ )"

Comment: meant to have the second one to be lower ... I'll just post as answer

Answer (score 0):

This query appears to produce the correct results, though it pointed out that you missed a line in your example output '27-May-2011 ... 27-May-2011 ... 2 ... 20'.

```
select id, [value], date as fromdate, (
        select top 1 date
        from key_value kv2
        where id = kv.id
            and [value] = kv.[value]
            and date >= kv.date
            and datediff(d, kv.date, date)  = (
                select count(*)
                from key_value
                where id = kv.id
                    and [value] = kv.[value]
                    and date > kv.date
                    and date <= kv2.date
            )
        order by date desc
    ) as todate
from key_value kv
where not exists (
    select *
    from key_value
    where id = kv.id
        and [value] = kv.[value]
        and date = dateadd(d, -1, kv.[date])
)
```

First it finds the min date records with the where clause, looking for records that do not have another record on the day before. Then the todate subquery gets the greatest date record by finding the number of days between it and min date then finding the number of records between the two and making sure they match. This of course assumes that the records in the table are distinct.

However if you are processing a massive table your best option may be to sort the records by key, id, date and then use a cursor to programmatically find the min and max dates as you loop over and look for values to change, then push them into a new table whether real or temp along with any other calculations you might need to do on other fields along the way.